# Setting up and customizing mail server to store mails in desired way

Tags: java, email, mail-server

I'm creating a website(say somesite.com) in Java. A part of the website is: users are provided with e-mail address (username@somesite.com) 
and can send & receive emails using the e-mail address and the website.

Now, the problem is to setup a mail server. I tried hMailServer but hMailServer uses its own database tables which is very difficult to 
use with the website database design.
Is there anyway to use mail server but store those emails in the way I want 
(in website database tables)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this reach your expectation, but take a look at Apache James:

http://james.apache.org/server/index.html